# When reviewing suggested edit, seeing post comments would be useful

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

Frequently when reviewing suggested edits, an OP will post some additional code, error or output as a comment. Someone requiring edit-review will (correctly) edit their post, and add the relevant code/error/output to the post itself. However, when reviewing the edit, there is no indication where the code came from as you are not shown the comments for the post on the review screen - it looks like it just appears out of nowhere. Since it's not always clear that the code came from a comment, you can't just automatically accept any added text.

As a workaround, you can track down the post (you have the poster's name), and look at the comments to verify that's in fact what's happening. However, this is time consuming, and likely people will just skip the review rather than accepting it. To better streamline the acceptance of helpful edits, could the comments for a post be added to the suggested edit review page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> you can track down the post (you have the poster's name)

This is not the easiest way to track down the post.  The title of the post is itself a link to the post.  Just open that link in a new tab.  And then you'd see not only the comment for this post, but the entire Q&A for better context.  So with this link to the post, including the comments is really an unhappy medium between the current state and including everything related to the post.

[image: Title is link to post]

Answer (score 3):

When I started doing reviews (not so long time ago), I though exactly that : there's regularly post where the review screen does not contain relevant information. But I was not really used enough to Meta at the moment to ask the question here.

So I keep on making reviews and found that the little `link` button on the right was an easy way to find all information about the post - it is even a nice tool for passing audits : if the post is deleted or closed, it must be *bad*, ;-).

More seriously, I now think that every third or tenth review requires me to look at original post to have more context. It is quite easy and quick, and I now find better to have just the minimum info for simple reviews and an easy access to remaining info when it is needed. To be honest, maybe usage helped me to find comfortable with that, but IMHO it is a correct if not the best mid way between a page containing all relevant information but that should be much larger and useless in simple cases and just the changed part which would clearly not be enough.

But I admit it is just my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The person doing the edit could just include in the edit comments that the code was added from OP comment.  That is what I did before being able to do non reviewed edits.  Lately I like to try and teach the OP how the site works and I will leave a comment along the lines of:

> The comment you made should be an [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/297323/edit) to you question.

Where edit is a hyperlinked to the edit link on their question.

As far as adding the comments to the review queue I am under the opinion the you should be able to figure out what is going on from what the editor said in the edit comment and the side by side comparison.  If it doesn't make sense with that the either reject/edit, reject or skip.

Comment: but - it's possible that they could say in the edit comment "added code" and then add some of their own code/output/etc... maybe because they are having a similar problem?

Comment: @MuertoExcobito They could but this site is based on the principle of giving the person the benefit of the doubt.  If we distrust everyone I don;tthink this site would be as good as it is.